# How to put 2 sets of 3 figures on 2 columns?

Tags: subfloats

I would like to put figures on 2 columns, 1st column; figure 1 with subfigures a, b and c, 2nd column: figure 2 with subfigures a, b and c.

```
(a) fig. a     | (a) fig. a
               |
               |
(b) fig. b     | (b) fig. b
               |
               |
(c) fig. c     | (c) fig. c
               |
               |
(1) fig. 1     | (2) fig. 2
```

I have tried with

```
\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{figure*}
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.5\linewidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{fig_a}
  \caption{Fig a}
\end{subfigure}
\\
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.5\linewidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{fig_b}
  \caption{Fig b}
\end{subfigure}
\\
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.5\linewidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{fig_c}
  \caption{Fig c}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Fig 1}

\columnbreak

\begin{figure*}
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.5\linewidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{fig_a}
  \caption{Fig a}
\end{subfigure}
\\
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.5\linewidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{fig_b}
  \caption{Fig b}
\end{subfigure}
\\
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.5\linewidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{fig_c}
  \caption{Fig c}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Fig 2}
\end{multicols}
```

but the figures remain on the same column, the left one.

How can I do that?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, which uses a `figure` to let things float and within uses two `minipage`s to house the `subfigure`s:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Example-Image}
        \caption{}\label{fig:leftA}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Example-Image}
        \caption{}\label{fig:leftB}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Example-Image}
        \caption{}\label{fig:leftC}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{Left}\label{fig:left}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Example-Image}
        \caption{}\label{fig:rightA}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Example-Image}
        \caption{}\label{fig:rightB}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Example-Image}
        \caption{}\label{fig:rightC}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{right}\label{fig:right}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]