# How to make a plot with 6 subfigures ( 2 figures in each row*3 rows)?

Tags: floats, subfloats, plot, subfig, figure-placement

I am trying to make a plot that would ideally have 3 rows and 2 columns such that the layout is

```
Row Description(A) |fig(a) |fig(b)|      
Row Description(B) |fig(a) |fig(b)|
Row Description(C) |fig(a) |fig(b)|
    Fig. 1: [Caption]
```

"Row Description" will include a mini description of each row.I want to have a hyperlink to each plots For example \ref{1Aa} should link to figure in row 1 and column 1.

The closest post that I came across is [How to put 2 sets of 3 figures on 2 columns?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/198193/how-to-put-2-sets-of-3-figures-on-2-columns). But I still can't make it work.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's quite rough, please forgive me. I used `tabularray` to layout.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{counter}
\begin{document}
\newcounter{cussublabel}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\cuslabel}{%
\stepcounter{cussublabel}%
\def\@currentlabel{(\alph{cussublabel})}%
\@currentlabel%
}
\makeatother
\begin{figure}
\begin{tblr}
{
colspec={Q[co=-1,c,m]Q[co=-1,c,m]Q[co=-1,c,m]},
columns={colsep=5pt},
rows={rowsep=5pt},
column{1}={preto={\cuslabel}},
}
\label{aaa}Row Description a&
\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth,valign=c]{example-image}&
\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth,valign=c]{example-image}\\
\label{bbb} Row Description b&
\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth,valign=c]{example-image}&
\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth,valign=c]{example-image}\\
\label{ccc} Row Description c&
\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth,valign=c]{example-image}&
\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth,valign=c]{example-image}\\
\end{tblr}
\caption{title}
\label{key}
\end{figure}
\figurename~\ref{aaa}\par
\figurename~\ref{bbb}\par
\figurename~\ref{ccc}\par
\figurename~\ref{key}
\end{document}
```

[image]